# How to browse website hosted in Test server within company network

Tags: hosting, website, iis-8.5, intranet

I have set up a website in IIS on QA server. I added binding and made entry in hosts file

```
Binding
IP: 123.43.12.45
Port: 80
HostName: mysite.mydomain.com

Hosts file entry
123.43.12.45 mysite.mydomain.com
```

At this point of time I'm on QA server through RDP access and able to browse website.
Now I logged out from QA server and tried to browse the website on my laptop but got following error:

```
This site can’t be reached
mysite.mydomain.com’s server DNS address could not be found
```

I am connected to my company network( through Cicso Anyconnect VPN) so I thought I would be able to access site even from my laptop.

Then I added following entry on my laptop hosts file

```
123.43.12.45 mysite.mydomain.com
```

Now I'm able to browse website.But in this way I have to ask client to make this entry in hosts file which I don't want.

Am I missing some configuration or there is any other way to access website without making entry in hosts file.

Answer (score 2):

The name needs to exist in DNS.

When you are on a remote network and the DNS server is normally unreachable, either configure the VPN client to use the desired DNS, or remote into a system on the server's network.

Comment: actually on same QA server one more website( cmssite.mydomain.com ) was already hosted and I'm able to browse that from my laptop even for this site I didn't find any entry in host file but for newly added site( mysite.mydomain.com ) I have to add entry in host file to run properly.

I don't have Server/Infra level understanding but as per your comment looks like for mysite.mydomain.com host name I have to ask our Infra team to add entry somewhere then only I will be able to browse from my laptop